# Bibliografía en latex

Tags: latex

Estoy creando un libro en latex.

En la sección del índice creo el capítulo Bibliografía pero luego al ingresar el código con bib

```
%Agregar las Bibliografías
\chapter{Bibliografía}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Biblio.bib}
\nocite{*}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que aparezca capítulo Bibliografía sin una subsection que diga referencias. Trae de ingresar el código:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{}
```

Pero, me dejaba un espacio enorme en el capítulo hacíendo alusión que el título "referencias" existe pero ahora es un caracter vacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes la bibliografía aparte en archivo .bib (llamémoslo `referencias.bib`) entonces puedes añadirla con el siguiente código en tu preámbulo:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencias.bib}
\nocite{*}
```

Y donde desees agregar la bilbiografía lo haces con:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliografía}]
```

En este caso al definir la opción `heading=bibintoc` se añadirá automáticamente al índice de tu proyecto, en cambio la segunda opción `title={Bibliografía}` es para cambiar el titulo de la bilbiografía al que tu desees.